# Clean way to detect if a Java library is being used on Android

Tags: java, android

What is a good way to detect inside a Java library, if it is being used on the Android platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say by definition this isn't clean.  Why do you think you need this functionality?

But the simplest way would be to try to dynamically load an Android class from the [ClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) (you obviously can't import it because then it only works when compiled against Android).

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("android.app.Activity");
```

Comment: there is a chance `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` to throw a `SecuritException` instead (on non android, for sure), so I'd just make a custom class compiled to android an do `try/catch(LinkageError _x)` w/o explicit call to the class loader. probably Class.forName will for as well

Comment: @bestsss, that's a good point.  However, you can just call `Class.forName("android.app.Activity");` No need to write a custom class for this (there might be another reason).

Comment: yeah I meant Class.forName ("will for" is a glaring spelling mistake). Usually the custom class proxies some standard JDK calls to android ones (TreeSet lacks few methods on android for instance), so it's a good place to ask if running on android.

Comment: I agree I think, this is by definition not clean, so I will keep it out of my library. The problem I was trying to solve was using a different config by default in case of android, but this can be done explicitly and that is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to detect this is to examine the [system properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).  For example:

```
  if (System.getProperty("java.vm.name").equals("Davlik")) {
      System.out.println("Android rules!");
  }
```

As with the "dynamically load an android class" approach, access to the system properties could be blocked by sandbox security.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that on the structure of the current stack trace is different between Android and plain JRE. On Android (both Dalvik and ART), the stack trace is always prepended by `dalvik.system.VMStack`. So, you could use this:

```java
public static boolean isAndroid() {
    StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    if (stack[0].getClassName().equals("java.lang.Thread")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```